# Superfish menu delay on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I am using superfish drop down menu. Everything is work great, however, I want to add some delay i.e. 0.75 seconds on mouseover. I found nothing related to adding delay on mousover. I can add delay to mouseout and speed value to 750 miliseconds but it just fading for 750 seconds but the menu is showing instantly when hovered.

I did like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu").superfish({
            delay:       0,
            speed:       750
        });
     });
 </script>
```

BTW, defaults for superfish looks in superfish.js like this:

```
$.fn.superfish.defaults = {
        popUpSelector: 'ul,.sf-mega', // within menu context
        hoverClass: 'sfHover',
        pathClass: 'overrideThisToUse',
        pathLevels: 1,
        delay: 800,
        animation: {opacity: 'show'},
        animationOut: {opacity: 'hide'},
        speed: 'normal',
        speedOut: 'fast',
        cssArrows: true,
        disableHI: false,
        onInit: $.noop,
        onBeforeShow: $.noop,
        onShow: $.noop,
        onBeforeHide: $.noop,
        onHide: $.noop,
        onIdle: $.noop,
        onDestroy: $.noop
    };
```

Can anybody help me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the hoverIntent pluging for superfish and setting the interval value for delaying the mouse over. Just for others to have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a function for onBeforeShow and have it sleep(750);

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I did tried like this as you suggested:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').superfish({
 delay:       0,
 onBeforeShow:      function(){ sleep:750; }
    });
});
</script>

This didn't work. Am I doing something wrong here?